# Stuck on LFS @ 5.7.1 "Glibc Installation"

Tags: linux, linux-from-scratch

I'm trying to build my own LFS system so I can better understand how linux works, but I'm stuck at 5.7.1 where you have to build Glibc. I've already un-tarred it into Sources, and logged into lfs using:

```
su - lfs
```

but whenever I try to do:

```
mkdir -v ../glibc-build
```

I get the error:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory '../glibc-build': Permission denied
```

How to fix this?

Comment: I've never done LFS but are you sure the `lfs` user is a superuser? What are the permissions on `glibc-build`?

Comment: According to section 5.3, you should be in the extracted package's top-level  source directory before executing the commands like `mkdir ../glibc-build`. What directory are you in when you do your mkdir?

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Can't believe I forgot this. Let me try this. I remember getting to that point but then still having problems actually doing the glibc configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you do not have enough permissions to create the build directory. If you have been doing anything from the `root` account then it will own the directories and any files created. By default, other users cannot modify other users files or directories. You either have to change permissions to allow `lfs` to create directories or continue working from `root`.

If you have been closely following LFS instructions, executing `chown -v lfs $LFS/tools` and `chown -v lfs $LFS/sources` as `root` should allow you to proceed as the `lfs` user.

[LFS 4.3](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/addinguser.html) explains the steps in detail.

Comment: How would I go about adding root permissions to the lfs user? If I recall correctly, during chapter 5 you're supposed to avoid using the root user because it would change where the packages would attempt to install.

Comment: I believe you are supposed to build everything as unprivileged user so doing `chown -v lfs $LFS/tools` and `chown -v lfs $LFS/sources` as `root` should do the trick. After executing both of those commands login back as `lfs` and things should be fine.

While I am at it - LFS avoids `root` because a single mistake can render your system useless and you really don't want that to happen when you have been painstakingly compiling everything by hand.